# Using WORKDAY to add days to a date including weekends, Excluding Public Holidays

Tags: excel, function

In cell `A1` I have a date

In cell `B1` a have an integer that represents a number of days

In range `$C$1:$C$20` I have the dates the represent the public holidays

I need to calculate in `C1` the date after adding the number of days in `B1` **including weekends** and **excluding only the range of public holidays**

I am trying to modify the formula in `C1`:

```
=WORKDAY(A1,B1, $C$1:$C$20)
```

Shall I count all the Saturdays and Sundays, and then subtract that number from `B1`?

Is there any other way (function) to add a number of days to a date, including weekends and excluding ONLY public holidays?

Comment: Depends on the Excel version. In newer versions there is [WORKDAY.INTL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-INTL-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). This can be used with a weekend string "0000000" which means no day is not a workday.

Comment: Excel 2013. WORKDAY.INTL allows you to define the days of the week considered as weekend. WORKDAY.INTL(start_date, days, [weekend], [holidays]). It would work for me if I could define [weekend] as null or zero. Bu it is not possible.

Comment: `=WORKDAY.INTL(start_date, days, "0000000", [holidays])`

Comment: didn't understand what's bothering you. Just use `=WORKDAY.INTL(A1,B1,"0000000", $C$1:$C$20)`

Comment: Fantastic! it is working. Thanks. Just have to understand why the 7 zeros

Comment: each `0` represents the day of the week.  `0` means not a day off.

Comment: Yes it works perfect!

Comment: Perfectly understood